# Prevent values transformation during deserialization/serialization

Tags: c#, json.net

My application does some changes in pretty big JSON files (not serialized .NET, just configs). The important moment - other JSON parts should stay untouched. The problem I faced is: during serialization/deserialization some of the property values transform in unwanted ways. Examples:

```
1.333147768201288e+16 -> 13331477682012880.0
1684715304.486056 -> 1684715304.4860561
0.0 -> 0
```

Some of these transformations take place in the deserialization stage and some - in the serialization stage. Some of them I can handle, but some becoming a nightmare.

Is there a way somehow tell the JSON module to leave **all** the values as-is, without a tiniest rounding/cutting/etc? is there an elegant way to do it without crutches and pain? Thanks!

PowerShell example:

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\newtonsoft.json\1.0.2.201\libs\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'

$json = '{
    "a": 1.333147768201288e+16,
    "c": 1684715304.486056
}'
$deserialized = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::DeserializeObject( $json )
$serialized = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject( $deserialized )

# transforms 'c' to 1684715304.4860561
write-host ( $deserialized | select * )

# transforms 'a' to 13331477682012880.0
write-host ( $serialized )
```

Comment: Why do you care about the number format in the JSON? As for the precision, you could use the `decimal` type instead of `double` in you model. `decimal` stores each decimal digit on its own, whereas double converts the number into a binary number often leading to tiny rounding errors.

Comment: Added an example. If I choose decimal, it breaks the 'a' value. Something always broken/changed after deserialization :(

Comment: Newtonsoft's `JsonTextReader` converts numeric values to `long` or `double` (or `decimal` if you use `FloatParseHandling.Decimal`).  It does not retain the underlying string representation of the number, so there there is no guarantee that the number will not be re-serialized in a different but equivalent format.

Comment: Now `JsonNode` and `JsonElement` from `System.Text.Json` do retain the underlying textual representation, so if you deserialize to either of those and re-serialize the format of the numeric tokens will be retained, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/xtiG8W.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to use System.Text.Json with Powershell, and your code example shows Powershell despite being tagged [tag:c#].  But see maybe [PowerShell to C# & back - JSON Seriazlie & Deserialize](https://dexterposh.github.io/posts/010-dotnet-pwsh-json/) by [Deepak](https://dexterposh.github.io/about/).  What version of Powershell are you using?

Comment: Specifically, can you use Powershell 7.2, which is built on [.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-72?view=powershell-7.3) so should have System.Text.Json.Nodes available?

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.4
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Have you tried something like the following:

```
using namespace System.Text.Json

Write-Host "Data:"
$data = '{
   "a": 1.333147768201288e+16,
   "c": 1684715304.486056
}'
Write-Host $data


Write-Host "JSON String to Object:"
$obj = [JsonSerializer]::Deserialize( $data, [Object] )
Write-Host $obj
Write-Host ""


Write-Host "Object to JSON String"
$json_str = ConvertTo-Json $obj
$json_str = [JsonSerializer]::Serialize( $obj, [Object] )
Write-Host $json_str
```

**Output:**

```
Data:
{
   "a": 1.333147768201288e+16,
   "c": 1684715304.486056
}
JSON String to Object:
{
   "a": 1.333147768201288e+16,
   "c": 1684715304.486056
}

Object to JSON String
{"a":1.333147768201288e+16,"c":1684715304.486056}
```

Seems to preserve values / formatting.